# How to create table in mysql when cast function is used

Tags: mysql

This is my table consists which consists of empid,salary_percentage:

```
empid   salary_percentage

10001     78.98 

10002     60.94362

10003     75.887278

10004     0

10005     100

10006     45.992772
```

I used this query to get the descending order of salary_percentage

```
select empid , salary_percentage from table order by cast(salary_percentage as unsigned) DESC;
```

I got the output like this

```
empid   salary_percentage

10005     100 

10001     78.98

10003     75.887278

10002     60.94362

10006     45.992772

10004     0
```

But if I want to create a table for this I am getting an error:

```
create table table2(select empid , salary_percentage from per order by cast(salary_percentage as unsigned) DESC);

error:Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '60.94362'
```

How can I rectify this?

Comment: Don't use an integer for the definition?   Or ditch the decimals. " create table table2(select empid , salary_percentage from per order by cast(salary_percentage as unsigned) DESC);" is that valid sql?!

Comment: How is the table per defined? Also, why do you use an `order by` clause in your create statement?  The order of insert is anyway irrelevant for further processing.